# Error al obtener el valor de una propiedad de un JSON

Tags: javascript

Estoy ejecutando una api la cual me muestra la cotización del Dólar. Al querer obtener el valor del dólar blue , me muestra un error al leer la propiedad

```
const apiUSD = "https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales";
const cotizacionDolar = await fetch(apiUSD);
const cotizacionJSON = cotizacionDolar.json();
console.log(cotizacionJSON[1].compra)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta con `console.log(cotizacionJSON[0]?.casa?.compra)

Answer (score 0):

La estructura de cada objeto es

```
{
    "casa": { 
        "compra": "0000"
        //propiedades
        }
}
```

Para acceder a la propiedad compra debes acceder primero a la propiedad casa.

```
console.log(cotizacionJSON[1].casa.compra)
```

Recuerda que la llamada al .json() del api fetch es asincrona tambien entonces tambien debe ser esperada con await.

```js
async function dolar() {
  const apiUSD = "https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales";
  const cotizacionDolar = await fetch(apiUSD);
  const cotizacionJSON = await cotizacionDolar.json();
  console.log(cotizacionJSON[1].casa.compra)
  
}

dolar();
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por comentar, probé de esa forma pero me muestra el mismo problema

Comment: Hola, ya edite mi respuesta, no me di cuenta la primera vez que vi tu codigo que no estabas haciendo el segundo await.

Comment: Pregunta, al ponerle el segundo await, lo que hacia es, al no convertir en json, se imprimia antes de que este listo. Por eso no me dejaba acceder a casas del json ?

Comment: Exacto, el objeto era una Promesa pendiente en ese momento.

Comment: esta es la respuesta, yo la probe y me funciono, igual le agregaria los signos de pregunta, por si algun dato llega null, quedando de esta manera   
`console.log('console dolar blue',cotizacionJSON[1]?.casa?.compra)`

Comment: Si, la respuesta es solamente el caso de éxito, hay mucha validacion que agregar, un bloque de try/catch seria lo ideal para trabajar con async/await.